# prevent auto-update of Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

One of the information at https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple states that ***“5. After you publish your app, whenever you want to change your app's listing or .crx file, use the dashboard to update them. To push an updated .crx file for your app, just increment the version number in the manifest, upload a new ZIP file to the dashboard, and publish the change. People who have already installed your app will automatically get the update.”***

As per that, whenever, for a given app, an updated CRX file (i.e., new version of app) is uploaded in the webstore, the client devices where the older version of app was previously installed would get updated (with the new version of app) automatically.

However, I’ve requirement, where the new version of the app shouldn’t get updated automatically - even if the new version of the app is uploaded in the 'webstore'.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Like this [How to disable Google Chrome extension autoupdate](//stackoverflow.com/q/27657617) ?

Comment: So you want manual updates?

Comment: Yes - this is to have manual updates. Is there any configuration that could be set in the manifest.json (or) in the 'webstore' which would prevent autoupdate of Chrome Apps?

Comment: You will need to implement a custom versioning system with the code of multiple versions included in the package.